# Clicking on the openlayers overview map button gives anomolous results

Tags: openlayers

I'm building a map interface based on Openlayers (ver. 6.0.1) and am noticing an odd behavior associated with the overview map button which is different than other buttons in the default controls or custom controls. Clicking the overview map button opens or closes the overview map and also responds as if the user has 'singleclicked' the map. I have a 'singleclick' function, so I see the results or non-results. Is there a reason for this behavior and is there a way to stop this behavior?

Comment: It also happens with the button for collapsible attributions.

Comment: Neither happened in v5.3.0 so I presume it is an unintended bug.

Comment: I've raised it as  a bug

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I hoped I wasn't losing it.

Comment: Mike, I confirmed the attributions button anomalous behavior.  I've also confirmed it didn't occur in 5.3.0.  Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried the overview map and map.on("click", f) but everything was fine. it didn't fire any click event on clicking overview button.

Comment: Map.on(”singleclick”, f) is where I see the described results.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ol-control button span {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

in the css fixes it, I have  proposed a pull request that be included in the OpenLayers css